# why do people say that RPython is an unpleasant language to program in

Tags: python, rpython

It is often stated that RPython is an unpleasant language to program in, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277174/are-generators-supported-in-rpython#comment7326713_6277174), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317707/game-library-with-support-for-rpython#comment21632036_15317707), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564865/133374) or [here](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#do-i-have-to-rewrite-my-programs-in-rpython).

However, for example [here](http://rpython.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/rpython-DLS08.pdf) in the original paper about RPython, it says quite the opposite:

> The result is a language that is more expressive than C# and Java, but
>   which does not compromise runtime efficiency. RPython was initially
>   designed for the specific purpose of implementing PyPy [25] (a Python
>   interpreter written in Python), but it has grown into a full-fledged
>   language in its own right.
>
> Currently, RPython can be used in many contexts: to develop
>   stand-alone programs, such as the Standard Interpreter itself; to
>   write highly efficient extension modules for CPython, which could only
>   be written in C in the past; to develop dynamic web applications
>   without the need to write JavaScript code; to produce efficient
>   libraries of classes and functions to be used by other .NET and Java
>   programs. In particular, RPython can be the ideal companion for all
>   those CPython, IronPython and Jython developers that so far have been
>   forced to write the parts of their programs that need high performance
>   in C, C# or Java.

A related question for using RPython as a general purpose language is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034027/developing-pypys-rpython-as-a-general-programming-language). I was also wondering about using RPython as a replacement for Cython. A related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133661/rpython-write-generic-native-library-write-cpython-c-module). There is also the [RPythonic project](https://code.google.com/p/rpythonic/).

Why is it that people recommend against using RPython?

Comment: Although it a lot of thought was put into writing this question, it is still not appropriate for this site.

Comment: Well, for me, it wasn't really clear whether this is just about debating or not. Seems to be the case - although I still don't know why because if clever people discourage others from using RPython, I thought there must be reasons. Seems people who are more knowledgeable than me think they are wrong and there aren't real reasons.

Comment: They say that because it's true. It *is* an unpleasant language to program in.

Comment: @delnan: Why is that? But actually that was just what I was asking in the question itself. As it was closed, it seems that it is debatable and cannot be answered.

Comment: This is a worthwhile question and should not have been closed.  There are in-fact some specific reasons that the PyPy team recommends that RPython not be used as a primary language for development.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: I trust your opinion. Voting to reopen.

Comment: It is a subset of python, much like asm.js is a subset of javascript. It is designed to be a compiler target and not a primary language.

Comment: And, I can see all the restrictions making it absolutely painful for a casual program.

Comment: @PauloScardine: Wrong. It is not a compiler target. A full interpreter was written *in* it, namely PyPy. And as you can read from the original paper (the part I quoted), it can be used in many contexts.

Comment: I'd say one reason is that RPython compiler's error messages are quite complicated, and sometimes could be unhelpful.

Comment: @OvermindJiang: That are all not real reasons. That can be improved, if that are the only problems. There must be other ones, otherwise I don't see why people are not doing this. Note that I got a small hint in the mail thread [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2013-June/011501.html) (both Carl and Armin have answered there). I'm just waiting here that someone with some deeper knowledge answers.

Comment: @Albert: you are technically correct; It's a subset of Python with a toolchain that translates RPython programs into an efficient version of that program for one of various target platforms. I will maintain the analogy to asm.js regarding the fact that both are subsets of dynamic languages designed for being easier to optimize than their parent languages. If you trade expressiveness for optimization, IMHO the resulting language will be less pleasant.

Answer (score 2):

from here:https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2013-June/011503.html

"

When people look at RPython, an obvious feature is that it is
syntactically identical to Python.  "RPython must be an easy language,
given that it has got the syntax of Python, which is easy".  This is a
common misconception.  In fact, pleasing the automatic type inference
process can be difficult.  It requires the programmer keeping in his
head the global types of his whole program, and carefully writing code
according to these implicit types.  The process is much harder for
newcomers, which don't have any written-down example to learn how to
manipulate the types --- precisely because they are implicit.
"

Answer (score 1):

I have made one file conversion program using RPython toolchain. Simple buffered file input and output. I can't imagine with my skills easier language to make such a fast, reliable, low bugs program.

What works and what doesn't is not well documented but once you find things out it is really nice set of tools to make small, fast and reliable programs.